# oauthplayground invalid grant, trying to get refresh token google oauth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-oauth

I got the temporary access token, serverAuthCode, web client id and its secret, i am trying to get refresh token from oathplayground but i am getting invalid grant error. I have rechecked the tokens many times but still getting same error. Here are the screenshots :

[image]

[image]

[image]

What can i do to get the refresh tokens ? For more information, i am using react-native-google-sign-in library, from this library, i got the 1. access_token, ServerAuthCode. From Google Developers console, i got the 1.Web Client Id 2.Client Secret , I am using these credentials inside the react native app and i am getting the tokens successfully, but the problem is sometimes they work and most of the times i get "invalid credentials" error when i try to use the access token, it is because the access token is expired, that's why i need the refresh token. If you have any idea why i am not able to get refresh token or how to get refresh token using another method, please let me know.

Comment: Which flow is used in your app?

Comment: Basically, the user is promoted with authentication using one of his email accounts in the app then he is asked to allow for permissions to upload files using google drive. After giving the permissions, i am getting the access_token, serverAuthCode and user info.

Answer (score 2):

I understood what i was doing wrong, i was using the serverAuthCode that was not new, it should be the latest one + the first time when you allowed the app for permissions, and it will work only first time, after you have exchanged it for a refresh token, it will not work again and will always give you grant_error. So after getting the refresh token you can get a new refreshed access token. I was using react-native-google-sign-in and was in need of refreshed token, read below to know more about the same.

For React-native-google-sign-in : 
The access token you will receive from `GoogleSignin.getTokens();` will only last for about an hour, to get a new access_token we need to send `serverAuthCode` to `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token` with fields : `client_id`, `client_secret`, `code`(this is serverAuthCode), `grant_type`(its value should be authorization_code), `redirect_uri`(can set it from developers console). Remember to only use the `serverAuthCode` that you get on your first attempt when you just allowed your app for the permissions FIRST TIME otherwise you will get grant_error every time. After getting the `refresh_token`, we need to get the new `access_token` using refresh token that we just got, so now just replace the value of `grant_type` from `authorization_code` to `refresh_token` and also replace the value of  `code` field to `refresh_token` , fill its value and send a post request to the same url, you will get a fresh `access_token`that will be valid for 1 hour.