# Google OAuth with id_token instead of access_token (Gooogle Business Communications)

Tags: google-oauth

I'm trying to create a Chatbot in **Gooogle Business Communications** (https://business-communications.cloud.google.com/), I have created the agent, the Webhook is properly configured and I downloaded the "Service account" json file.

I'm able to receive messages in my webhook, now I want to reply back to the user, and here is the problem. I'm following this [instructions for Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) (JWT manually created and executing through postman) and also I'm trying with the [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)

In both cases, I have a response from https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token but the problem is that I'm getting only an `id_token`, but I need an `access_token`.

This is the response when this endpoint [https://businesscommunications.googleapis.com/v1/partners/{Partner_ID}](https://businesscommunications.googleapis.com/v1/partners/%7BPartner_ID%7D) is executed using `id_token`:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```

}

I have installed the [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) command line tool and by executing next command I'm able to obtain a valid `access_token`:

```
oauth2l fetch --type oauth --credentials ./service_account_key.json --scope businesscommunications
```

With this token I can execute the previous endpoint (or the reply message endpoint).

Maybe there is a parameter that I'm missing when I try to get the `access_token`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google 'google oauth playground' and use your credentials to generate the access token.

Useful resources:

[How can I verify a Google authentication API access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359472/how-can-i-verify-a-google-authentication-api-access-token?rq=1)

[oauthplayground invalid grant, trying to get refresh token google oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191534/oauthplayground-invalid-grant-trying-to-get-refresh-token-google-oauth)